# how to Remove (&lt;) and ([CDATA[[) from SOAP response using java?

Tags: java, soap, response

please help me out for the below problem, i am trying since long time(3 weeks) but not able to get the proper resolution.I have to complete it ASAP ,as my so many webservice output depends on the custom return string.

I have written java code using javax.jws.

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Use;

    String returnStr = null;

    String responseCodeStart = "<responseCode>";
    String responseCodeEnd = "</responseCode>";
    String responseMessageStart = "<responseMessage>";
    String responseMessageEnd = "</responseMessage>";
```

**Return Custom String in JAVA to SOAP response/Output String :::::::::**

```
 returnStr = "\r\n" + responseCodeStart + "1000" + responseCodeEnd + "\r\n" + responseMessageStart + "Registration successful>>" + responseMessageEnd + "\r\n";
```

**Problem :**

```
1)  I am getting (&lt;) tag instead of (<)
2) I am getting ([CDATA[[) tag in response.
```

**SOAP RESPONSE :**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:registerUserResponse xmlns:ns2="http://impl.timecapsule.com/">
         <return>&lt;responseCode>1102&lt;/responseCode>
&lt;responseMessage> [!CDATA[[Please provide username] &lt;/responseMessage></return>
      </ns2:registerUserResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

****Resolution needed:****

```
    1) &lt; to remove
    2) CDATA to remove

I want to retrieve it as XML object instead of String using java code.


THANKS
```

Comment: This question is a train wreck, please consider fixing your formatting issues and provide a more complete java snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Framework, if you want to provide or consume a webservice via SOAP.
You don't have to use any starting-tags or end-tags, the framework will handle this.

```
String responseCodeStart = "<responseCode>";
String responseCodeEnd = "</responseCode>";
String responseMessageStart = "<responseMessage>";
String responseMessageEnd = "</responseMessage>";
```

If you return a String (not a number inside a class), the encodings are correct. You return a String with special encoded Chars.  They HAVE to be encoded this way. otherwise you will create malformed XML.

[javax.jws Tutorial at Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbor.html)
[Webservice-Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/)